# Force Enzyme mount() to validate PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, validation, jestjs, enzyme, react-proptypes

I am trying to write Jest tests using Enzyme's `mount()` function that ensures an error is thrown when bad data is given to my React component, but `mount()` only performs PropTypes validation the first time `mount()` is called. With the following test suite using improperly formatted props:

```
it('should throw a "Failed prop type" Error', () => {
        expect(globalNavigation).toThrow("Failed prop type");
    });
it('should throw a "Failed prop type" Error', () => {
        expect(globalNavigation).toThrow("Failed prop type");
    });
```

the first test passes, but the second fails because React is not validating the props. How can I force the `mount()` function to validate PropTypes?

Answer (score 1):

Your component receives props from a parent. Therefore, you should test the parent component to make sure it passes the right props to its children. You should not test that child component to see if it was indeed given the right props -- you are responsible for faking those props. Because of that, I highly suggest you use shallow instead of mount.

Defining PropType checks is a way for developers to be warned during development that they might have forgotten to pass certain props to a component. I don't think you should be testing that... That is already a test in itself. PropTypes check are not supposed to show up in production.